# How can I refresh a page every 5 minutes starting at 8:01 a.m. and then 8:06 a.m. and so on.

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>
<head>Harshal</head>

<script>

var limit="5:0"
var doctitle = document.title
var parselimit=limit.split(":")
parselimit=parselimit[0]*60+parselimit[1]*1

function beginrefresh(){
  if (parselimit==1)
    window.location.reload()
  else{
    parselimit-=1
    curmin=Math.floor(parselimit/60)
    cursec=parselimit%60
  if (curmin!=0)
    curtime=curmin+" minutes and "+cursec+" seconds left until page refresh!"
  else
    curtime=cursec+" seconds left until page refresh!"
    document.title = doctitle + ' (' + curtime +')'
    setTimeout("beginrefresh()",1000)
  }
}

if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener("load", beginrefresh, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
  window.attachEvent("load", beginrefresh)

</script>
</html>
```

This is my demo code. I'm refreshing the page every 5 minutes when someone clicks on the link and the tab title counts down the 5 fives. However, I cannot figure out how I can start the refresh at 8:01 a.m and then again at 8:06 am and then again at 8:11 a.m. and just keeps going and doesn't depend on when someone clicks on it.

Any help?

Comment: What link?  This page looks like it starts the refresh cycle as soon as it's loaded.  And your description sounds like it's successfully refreshing in 5-minute intervals.  I don't see anything in here related to any "click" events.  It's not clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: The code works, but you want it only to start at 8:01 AM? Please explain the use case. What is meant to happen when say somebody opens the page at 8:00 AM or 8:02 AM?

Comment: @David By click, I meant when someone clicks on the link to get to this page. The problem is that I want to refresh the page at 8:01 am and then 8:06 am. I want the page to actually refresh on world time every 5 minutes instead of 5 minutes from when someone clicks on it. I hope this explains it.

Comment: @Greg Yes, when someone clicks on it at 8:02, it refreshes at 8:07. I want the page to refresh it at 8:06 no matter when someone clicks on it. The last refresh should be at 8:01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use SetInterval

1. SetInterval for every minute (1000*60)
2. GetTime in Hours and Minutes separately
3. Start after 8am or anytime after 8am
4. Check every 5 mins to refresh
5. refresh window

```js
    setInterval(function(){
      var currTimeHr = new Date().getHours();
      var currTimeMin = new Date().getMinutes();
      if(currTimeHr >= 8){  //start at 8 or at any point after 8am
        if(currTimeMin%5 === 0){  // check every 5 mins
          window.location.reload(true); //refresh page
        }
      }
    }, 1000*60)
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/MXVWxb?editors=1010

Comment: deleted my answer because this is the best answer.

Comment: change the if condition to if(currTimeHr >= 7 && currTimeMin > = 59 )

Comment: may be if condition executes and redirection and page load ..all together happens in 30secs

Comment: any change in refresh time??

Comment: I tried adding the following, but it still doesn't refresh.                                              var currTimeSec = new Date().getSeconds(); 
                                                                                                                 if(currTimeHr >= 8 && currTimeMin >= 0 && currTimeSec == 30 ) 
                                                                                                           if(currTimeMin%5 === 0){  
             window.location.reload(true); 
             } 
        }
              }, 1000*60)

Comment: instead of running for every min,, make setInterval run for every sec i.e 1000 instead of 1000 * 60 , so that it will be precise and starts from 8 exactly

Comment: I totally forgot about the interval. It works perfectly now! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Harshal  Glad it worked for you :) .. please mark my post as answer, if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

use set interval.

```
setInterval(function() {
    window.location.reload();
}, 300000);
```

setinterval is in ms (5mins = 300k ms)

Comment: How would it start at 8:01 a.m.?

Answer (score 0):

The new page (after refresh) has no awareness of the previous page's state. So you need a way to pass that state forward, through a query parameter or something.

My approach would be to just reload the page when they clicked the link, and have the new page set itself to refresh after 5 minutes (keeping the same url so we're loading the page with the refresh code).

```js
if(window.location.search.includes('refresh')){
  setTimeout(function(){//we're in "refresh mode" so just wait 5 minutes and do it again
    location.href = location.href;
  }, 1000 * 60 * 5);
}
```

```html
<a href="?refresh">refresh every five minutes</a>
```

the example doesn't seem to work because the navigation. but it should work in theory

Answer (score 0):

To start at specified time use the following "wait" function

```
var startHour = 8;
var startMinute = 5;

function wait() {
    var startTime = currentTime = new Date();
    startTime.setHours(startHour);
    startTime.setMinutes(startMinute);

    if (startTime < currentTime) {
        setTimeout(wait, 1000);
    } else {
        // run refresh function here
    }
}
```